# Relative Jump in GameBoy emulator isn't jumping to where it should

Tags: c#, emulation, gameboy

I'm working on a GameBoy emulator on C#, and testing it with Blargg's test ROMs (cpu_instrs from [here](https://github.com/retrio/gb-test-roms/tree/master/cpu_instrs)). I'm going through tests individually, and now I'm using `07-jr`,`jp`,`call`,`ret`,and `rst`. I am comparing my results with bgb's debugger. Now, when I get to `0209`, where it runs the opcode `0x20 (JR NZ)`, bgb jumps to `0x206`, but my emulator jumps to `0x306`.

This is my current code for that instruction:

```
if (Processor.GetZeroFlag() == 0)
{
    byte jumpOffset = Processor.ReadNextByte();
    ushort targetAddr = (ushort)(Processor.GetPC() + 2 + jumpOffset);

    Processor.SetPC(targetAddr);
    Processor.FinishedIntruction(0, 8, 2);
    break;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not taking the branch");
    Processor.FinishedIntruction(2, 8, 2);
    break;
}
```

`ReadNextByte()` returns the next byte from memory (reads from PC + 1), in this case it's FB (which, according to bgb, is correct). As far as I understood, I have to add FB to the current PC, and the instruction's length (2), but doing that I end up in 306 as I already explained.

Is there something here that I'm missing — some error in my code that I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte jumpOffset = Processor.ReadNextByte();
```

It should be `sbyte` giving -5 instead of 0xFB.